# Colorize polygons shapes from geoJSON in MapBox Android SDK

Tags: android, mapbox, geojson

I'm using a geoJSON to display a shape in Android MapBox.
In the geoJSON I've got a lot of polygons and each of them has a value in "properties" JSONObject, here is an exemple:

```
{
"geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [
                2.3303745,
                39.841098
            ],
            [
                2.3303464,
                39.8410976
            ],
            [
                2.3303261,
                39.8411054
            ]
        ]
    ]
},
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {
    "value": 169
}
}
```

I would like to fill the polygon with a specific colour according to the value.

### What I currently do and get

```
GeoJsonSource geoJsonSource = new GeoJsonSource("geojson",stringbuilder.toString());
mapboxMap.addSource(geoJsonSource);
mapboxMap.addLayer(new FillLayer("geojson", "geojson"));
```

[image: What I get]

### Question

What should I do to colorize the shape?

1. Add in the JSON a "fill" value to "poperties" Object? (didn't work for me,yet.)
2. Parse the JSON manually and use "fillColor" function in "PolygonOptions" object? (will add a lot of work, because there is a lot of polygons)

### What I want

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONArray features = json.getJSONArray("features");

//Get the value for each features and create geojsonsource
for (int i = 0; i < features.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject feature = features.getJSONObject(i);
    Double value=-1.0;

    if (feature != null) {
        JSONObject properties = feature.getJSONObject("properties");
        if (properties != null && properties.has("value")) {
            value = properties.getDouble("value");
        }
        GeoJsonSource geoJsonSource = new GeoJsonSource("geojson" + i, feature.toString());

        if (!values.contains(value))
            values.add(value);
        list_value_geojson.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(value, geoJsonSource));
    }
}
```

in the postExecute function of my AsyncTask:

```
for (int i=0; i < list_value_geojson.size(); i++){
    Map.Entry<Double, GeoJsonSource> entry = list_value_geojson.get(i);
    if (mapboxMap != null && entry != null) {
        mapboxMap.addSource(entry.getValue());
        FillLayer fillLayer = new FillLayer(entry.getValue().getId(), entry.getValue().getId());
        fillLayer.setProperties(PropertyFactory.fillColor(Color.parseColor(hashMap    Colors.get(entry.getKey()))));
    mapboxMap.addLayer(fillLayer);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Until data driven styling arrives in the next release, you'll need to create separate layers for each color and overlay them on top of each other. Contrary to what you might think, this shouldn't hinder performance, just a bit more work :)

Comment: Ok, so I start to parse the JSON and create a GeoJsonSource with each "feature" object.
Create a FillLayer with each geojsonsource and set fillcolor property according to the corresponding value.

I made that, it works. But it makes a couple of seconds to display I don't know if it's normal.

Thank you

Comment: Parsing GeoJSON can add a slight delay since it is being loaded into memory.